# How do I use the Google V8 Engine in a different c++ Project?

Tags: javascript, c++, v8, embedded-v8

If I import the `.lib` and `.h` files in the Google V8 Engine, it will attempt to use them in a different c ++ project.

Do I need to import a file of any name?

When the source of the `v8` was compile and build,

- cctest
- fuzzer_support
- generate-bytecode-expectations
- gmock
- gtest
- icui18n
- icuuc
- inspector_protocol
- json_fuzzer_lib
- mksnapshot
- parser_fuzzer_lib
- regexp_fuzzer_lib
- unittests
- v8
- v8_base_0
- v8_base_1
- v8_base_2
- v8_base_3
- v8_external_snapshot
- v8_libbase
- v8_libplatform
- v8_libsampler
- v8_nosnapshot
- v8_simple_json_fuzzer
- v8_simple_parser_fuzzer
- v8_simple_regexp_fuzzer
- v8_simple_wasm_asmjs_fuzzer
- v8_simple_wasm_fuzzer
- wasm_fuzzer_lib
- wasm_asmjs_fuzzer_lib

name file is generated.

I simply use the `v8`, and it outputs a run value of `javascript`.

My guess, seems to use only "`v8.lib`, `v8_base (0,1,2,3) .lib`" and "`v8.h`".

Is the sample code in a new c ++ project by copying the contents of the "`hello-world.cc`", made a cpp file. And I run, "`LNK2019`", "`LNK1120`" error occurs.

> 1>----- Build started: Project: v8Application, Configuration: Debug Win32 -----
>   1>  v8Application.cpp
>   1>v8Application.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function"class v8::Platform * __cdecl v8::platform::CreateDefaultPlatform(int)" (?CreateDefaultPlatform@platform@v8@@YAPAVPlatform@2@H@Z) 1>c:\users\kito\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\v8Application\Debug\v8Application.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

It seems must not defined "platform :: CreateDefaultPlatform" part is turned only in 'libplatform.h' declaration.
However, I would add "src \ libplatform \ default-platform.cc" the platform :: CreateDefaultPlatform has been defined, other error occurs in the add.

"`Ws2_32.lib`, `winmm.lib`" was also added to the project of the Additional Dependencies property.

How do I do this?

Comment: For reference, I use vs2015 & Windows 10.

Comment: `different console` - different in what way?

Comment: I made a "win32 console application" project of vs2015. I have tried the test put the "hello-world" example sentence in cpp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create your project and then LINK with V8, but you **must not** add V8's source files to your project.

The first thing to do is to compile V8 and take note of where the libraries were generated (or copy them to the directory of your choice). The same applies to V8's include files, they must be available in order to be included in your project (it is not advisable to copy them to your project directory).

In your console project's settings go to `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies` and put `v8.lib` there. If the error is still present work you might want to add `v8_libplatform.lib` too.

Something similar applies to the include files, in your project settings you should go to `C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories` and add V8's include directory  there.

But remember, you must first compile v8 alone and expose the lib and include directories to your new project.

**Update:**

Your project file indicates that you configured Your project only for the configuración "Release", but the output above indicates that you are compiling in Debug mode.

Project config:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    ...
    <Link>
        <AdditionalDependencies>ws2_32.lib;winmm.lib;v8.lib;v8_base_0.lib;v8_base_1.lib...
    </Link>
<ItemDefinitionGroup
```

Compiler output above:

```
1>----- Build started: Project: v8Application, Configuration: Debug Win32 -----
```

You must configure your project for all configurations, or at least test it using the configuration you've setup.

On the other hand, `v8_libplatform.lib` is not in the list of additional dependencies, you may want to add it.

Comment: I have copied the contents of the "hello-world" of v8 example source to the new project.  Did I use the wrong way?  "Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies" and "C / C ++ of -> General -> Additional Include Directories" was setting.

Comment: The new project of the location, "C: \ Users \ kito \ Documents \ Visual Studio 2015 \ Projects \ v8Application".  Configuration of v8Application is, include folders and lib folder, there is a v8Application.cpp files and project files.  In the lib folder "v8.lib, v8_base_0.lib, v8_base_1.lib, v8_base_2.lib, v8_base_3.lib, v8_libbase.lib, v8_libplatform.lib, there is a v8_nosnapshot.lib" file.

Comment: I was set the v8.lib and v8_base (0,1,2,3) in the "Linker - > Input-> Additional Dependencies".  In the include folder there is a h file of "v8, v8config, v8-debug, v8-experimental, v8-platform, v8-profiler, v8-testing, v8-util, v8-version".  And libplatform folder is in the include folder. There is a "libplatform, v8-tracing 'h file is in.  Version is different but "include folder", please refer to the "include" in the "master" from the "https://github.com/v8/v8/" link

Comment: Would you mind uploading your `.vcxproj` to gist.gihub.com/ and providing the path where V8 libs are located?

Comment: I posted the contents of the `.vcxproj` file and the `.cpp` file. [https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8e5bc61a057d59735bb4de015a7d8f6d](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8e5bc61a057d59735bb4de015a7d8f6d)  Please check.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ichramm. test was seen both Debug and Release, `. vcxpoj file` when to upload is being tested in Release mode. I have tried to also add `v8-libplatform.lib`, many of `LNK2001`, `LNK2019` error occurs. <code>#ifdef NDEBUG
#ifdef _DEBUG
#undef _DEBUG
#endif
#endif</code>  I tried to test using the code but was the same.

Comment: I today, was found look to try in other ways. I dropped the lib files of some of this. Need to import is not know where to find a list of lib file, it seems to have been a problem. I am currently in the test, but seems to have can be solved if the study than a little bit.
I am very grateful to give an answer.